# Java не видит main, jar собран при помощи maven

Tags: maven, java

Почему-то Java не видит `main`, как запускать проект собраный в `maven`?

Comment: покажите какой командой проводили сборку

Comment: Посмотрите на манифест, скорее всего в манифесте не указан `Main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй так mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.vineetmanohar.module.Main"

детали тут http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/11/3-ways-to-run-java-main-from-maven/

Answer (score 2):

укажите mainclass при сборке проекта при помощи плагина

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>com.project.App</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

[ссылка](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html)